# QGIS Plugin executing function with parameters

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm creating a QGIS plugin that will load specific layers from our server, so inexperienced GIS users (e.g., upper management) can access key, up-to-date, layers with single clicks. I've created the plugin using "Plugin Builder" and QT designer. I have defined one main function that loads a vector layer (from a specified location) and applies a style file (from a specified location), called loadVector. Ideally, I want to pass loadVector the paths of the .shp and style file when the pushbuttons are clicked.

Below is a the dialog.py where there is one pushbutton "pb_BRLakes" that is to load a .shp from a GDB and apply a style path using the loadVector function.

```
import os
from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets
from qgis.core import *

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'datalink_dialog_base.ui'))


class DataLinkDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(DataLinkDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pb_BRLakes.clicked.connect(lambda: loadVector("T:/Vancouver_Technical/","BackRiverRegion/GIS_Products/ESRI_GDB/NU_Topographic.gdb|layername=BR_TOP_HYD_ln_076GLakeswithNames","BackRiver Lakes","C:/Users/daniel.coutts/Desktop/ShapeFiles/test/WaterBodyStyleFile.qml"))

    def loadVector(drivePath,filePath,fileName,stylePath):
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(drivePath+filePath,fileName)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        layer.loadNamedStyle(stylePath)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I have tried many different options, and thought a lambda function would be the way to go, but I'm still running into issues.

Comment: What errors occur during code execution?

Comment: The error I get is "NameError: name 'loadVector' is not defined". This includes having self in the method definition.

I have gotten it to work for both rasters and vectors by including the paths in the function and calling "self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadVector)", but this creates a huge number of functions for the toolbar. Passing the file paths in function call would be much more elegant.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `self` to the line where you both define and call `loadVector` function.

```
    ....
    #                                       vvvv
    self.pb_BRLakes.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loadVector("T:/Vancouver_Technical/",...))

#              vvvv
def loadVector(self, drivePath, filePath, fileName, stylePath):
    ....
```